# What is the proper way to transpose a 2D matrix coming from java, to a C++ function, then get the result back to java in android development?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm currently learning android native development with android studio, and I want to learn some of the best practices and dos and don't when developing native android applications.

For educational purposes I tried to create a **native transpose function**, I ended up successfully implemented the said native function that returns a correct transpose version of the original matrix passed in to it, but I'm not so sure if my implementation is correct, specially in the memory management and release calls.

This is the native transpose function definition in my MainActivity.class:

```java
private native int[][] transpose(int[][] arr, int row, int column);
```

And this is the C++ JNI declaration of the same native function:

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_example_nativeapp_MainActivity_transpose(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject,
        jobjectArray arr,
        jint row,
        jint column)
{
    jclass jintArrayClass = env->FindClass("[I");
    jint **row_elements = new jint*[row];

    for (jsize i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        auto current_row = (jintArray) env->GetObjectArrayElement(arr, i);
        row_elements[i] = env->GetIntArrayElements(current_row, nullptr);
        // Line Q1
        // env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(current_row, row_elements[i], JNI_ABORT);
    }

    jint **transposed_row_elements = new jint*[column];
    for (jsize i = 0; i < column; ++i) {
        transposed_row_elements[i] = new jint[row];
        for (jsize j = 0; j < row; ++j) {
            transposed_row_elements[i][j] = row_elements[j][i];
        }
    }

    jobjectArray transposed = env->NewObjectArray(column, jintArrayClass , nullptr);

    for (jsize i = 0; i < column; ++i) {
        // Line Q2
        jintArray curr_row = env->NewIntArray(row);
        env->SetIntArrayRegion(curr_row, 0, row, transposed_row_elements[i]);
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(transposed, i, curr_row);
    }

    for (jsize i = 0; i < column; ++i) {
        delete [] transposed_row_elements[i];
    }

    delete [] transposed_row_elements;
    delete [] row_elements;

    return transposed;
```

- I wonder If have mistakes in this implementation specially when using `JNIEnv`?
- When I enabled the comment out code, I'm getting the wrong result, But shomewhere I have read that we should always call `ReleaseXXX()` when we call `GetXXX()`, how can I get around this?

  ```cpp
  // Line Q1
  // env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(current_row, row_elements[i], JNI_ABORT);
  ```
- Also do I need to release the `curr_row` in `\\ Line Q2` block?
- In C++ when we allocate arrays with the `new` keyword we should always call the `delete` keyword... is this also the case in native android development, specially when passing these heap allocated arrays in the methods of `JNIEnv`, like when creating new jobjects, jobjectArray, jprimitiveArray?

**Overall I just wanted to see a much more clean and proper implementation of this native transpose function with nice explanations that I can learn and pickup.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, every JNI invocation has a table of "local references" of fixed size. Every object you allocate or get back from a method call takes up a slot in this local reference table. If you fill up the local reference table, all such operations will fail. That is why the JNI provides release operations to free up these local references.

If you take a high level view:

- the first for loop takes all the incoming matrix rows into the local reference table
- the second for loop does no JNI operations
- the third for loop allocates the result matrix plus one object per row.

Realistically, you cannot release the values of `row_elements` until you have walked each array in turn. So if you do that after the second loop everything should be fine. However, local references are released automatically when the JNI method returns, so you could just leave them be.

As for your final question: no, Java is garbage collected. If you allocate something and do not reference it from somewhere, the JVM will clean it up for you on the next GC cycle.

Comment: I just want to clarify, in the line `row_elements[i] = env->GetIntArrayElements(current_row, nullptr);` if ever it returns a pointer array copy, that return value is a **"local reference"**? hence even though it is a C pointer array, it will still be deallocated by the JVM since it was created using the `JNIEnv`?

So there is no need to call `free()` or `delete []` on its returned pointer?

Comment: That returns a pointer to a native memory buffer that may or may not be thr same as the storage for the Java array